# High school contest math problem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, contest-math, solution-verification

This is a calculus problem from a high school math contest in Greece,from 2012.

I wish to know some solutions for this. I attempted to solve it.

> Let $f:\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ differentiable such that $\lim_{x \to +\infty}f(x)=+\infty$ and $\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=2$.Show that $$\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x^{2012}}=+\infty$$

Here is my attempt:

$\frac{f(x)}{x^{2012}}=e^{\ln{\frac{f(x)}{x^{2012}}}}$

Now $\ln{\frac{f(x)}{x^{2012}}}=\ln{f(x)}-2012\ln x=\ln{x}\left( \frac{\ln{f(x)}}{\ln{x}}-2012\right)$

Now from hypothesis we see that $\lim_{x \to +\infty}\ln{f(x)}=+\infty$

By L'Hospital's rule we have that $$\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{\ln{f(x)}}{\ln{x}}=\lim_{x \to +\infty}x \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=2(+\infty)=+\infty$$

Thus $$\lim_{x \to +\infty}\ln{x}\left( \frac{\ln{f(x)}}{\ln{x}}-2012\right)=+\infty$$

Finally $\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x^{2012}}=+\infty$

Is this solution correct?

If it is,then are there also  better and quicker ways  to solve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can't we simply say that f(x) is equivalent to exp(2x) when x goes to infinity?

Comment: Marios.I think it is fine.+1. One remark .While correct I personally try to avoid something like $2(+\infty)$.

Comment: @Jeanba Maybe, if you can work out how to be sufficiently exact about what "equivalent when $x$ goes to infinity" means. It's certainly a good intuitive argument for why it ought to be true.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you can just use de l’Hopital inductively:

Given $n \in \Bbb{N}$, we have (since the numerator and denominator diverge):
$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{x^n} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f’(x)}{nx^{n-1}} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x) \frac{f’(x)}{f(x)}}{nx^{n-1}} = \frac{2}{n} \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x^{n-1}} $

So inductively we get:

$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{x^n} = \frac{2^n}{n!} \lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = \infty$

Comment: user622002.Nice answer.

Comment: This is really slick.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an approach that only uses the easily proved fact that

$\underset{x\to\infty }\lim\frac{e^x}{p(x)}=\infty\  \text{whenever}\  p \ \text{is a polynomial}. \tag1$

Indeed, there is an $x_0\in \mathbb R^+$ such that $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}>1$ for all $x>x_0.$ Then,

$\displaystyle\int^x_{x_0}\frac{f'(t)}{f(t)}dt>x-x_0\Rightarrow \ln f(x)-\ln f(x_0)>x-x_0\Rightarrow f(x)>(f(x_0)e^{-x_0})\cdot e^x \tag2.$

Divide $(2)$ by $x^{2012}$ and invoke $(1)$ to conclude.

Comment: +1....  before the constest,no theory of integration was covered but nice solution though,i will keep it in mind..is my approach correct?

Comment: Matematleta.Nice.

Comment: @Matematleta Not sure if the assumption $f \to \infty$ really is superfluous. Couldn't $f$ and $f'$ be both negative so that you can not even write down the expression $\operatorname{ln} f (x)$?

Comment: By the way and in response to @MariosGretsas' objection:
There is no need to use an integral in this proof. One could argue that - under appropriate conditions - the mean value theorem yields 
$$\operatorname{ln} f(x) - \operatorname{ln} f(x_0) =  \frac{f'(\xi)}{f(\xi)} \cdot ( x - x_0) \qquad \text{for some } \xi \in (x_0, x)$$
and from this equation one can deduce your estimate.

Comment: @BrunoKrams yes, indeed, +1

Comment: @BrunoKrams since $f'/f\neq 0$ for $x$ large enough the integral is $\ln |f(x)|-|f(x_0)|$  and so there is no problem there, but you are right: $f$ might approach $-\infty$ as $x\to \infty$ so the condition $f\to \infty$ is necessary.

Comment: @Matematleta +1 for your l’Hospital-free proof. I appreciate that

Answer (score 4):

Credit to user622002.

Show $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{f(x)}{x^n}=\infty$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Induction:

Base case: $n=0$ √.

Hypothesis:

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{f(x)}{x^n}=\infty$;

L'Hospital:

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{f(x)}{x^{n+1}}=$

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{f(x)(f'(x)/f(x))}{(n+1)x^n}$;

For large enough $x$: $f'(x)/f(x)>1$;

$(1/(n+1))\dfrac{f(x)}{x^n}\lt$

$ \dfrac{f(x)(f'(x)/f(x)}{(n+1)x^n}$.

Taking limits, invoking the hypothesis for the left hand side, we get

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{f(x)}{x^{n+1}}=\infty$.

Comment: Is my solution ok though?

Comment: @PeterSzilas, you wrote hypothesis: $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x^n}=0$ and it should be $n\in\mathbb N_0$ because $0\in\mathbb N_0$

Comment: VerkovtsevaKatya. Thanks for your comment. Actually as far as I know $0 \in \mathbb{N}$, if you want the positive integers one could write for example  $\mathbb{Z^+}$.

Comment: According to the original Peano axiomatisation that we use at our uni, $1$ isn't a successor, therefore we define $\mathbb Z^+:=\mathbb N=\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$. However, I searched the internet to check it and saw the modern version includes $0$. My mistake for correcting you, your statement was legitimate as well.

Comment: VerkovtsevaKatya. No mistake correcting me:) Happy New Year.